# Get Next working day using variable

Tags: date

I want to extract the next working day from the date generated by the script and assigned to variable `last_day`

Let's say variable `last_day` has a value `last_day=20190426` i want to get `next_day=2019-04-29` if  value of `last_day=2019-04-17` then `next_day=2019-04-18`. Scenario is if last_day is friday print next_day as monday else print next day date.

Not sure how can i make below command to work with variable.

```
date +%Y-%m-%d -d "+$(( ( $(date +%w)==5 )?3:1 )) days"
```

Tried this, but it's not working.

```
next_day=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "+$(( ( $(${last_day} +%w)==5 )?3:1 )) days")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
 last_day=20190426
 date -d "$last_day +$( if [ `date -d $last_day +%w` == 5 ]; then echo 3; elif [ `date -d $last_day +%w` == 6 ]; then echo 2; else echo 1; fi ) days" +"%Y%m%d"
```

The input may be of any day. so

- if input fall on 5th(Friday) day of the week will add 3.
- if input fall on 6th(Saturday) day of the week will add 2.
- else add 1 for all other days of the week